# CoreData: Values being set to nil when saving for some reason

Tags: swift, core-data

For some reason, I check no non-optional values are nil and save them, but they get rejected in saving:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1570 \"sectionId is a required value.\" UserInfo={NSValidationErrorObject=<CDChazaraState: 0x6000006912c0> (entity: CDChazaraState; id: 0x600002592580 <x-coredata:///CDChazaraState/tBE7528D1-1182-4234-8F64-AD7361A7836D20>; data: {\n    chazaraPoint = \"0x600002592620 <x-coredata:///CDChazaraPoint/tBE7528D1-1182-4234-8F64-AD7361A7836D21>\";\n    chazaraState = nil;\n    date = \"2022-09-12 14:35:00 +0000\";\n    pointId = nil;\n    scId = nil;\n    sectionId = nil;\n    stateId = \"CS1674394592.503487313\";\n    status = 4;\n}), NSLocalizedDescription=sectionId is a required value., NSValidationErrorKey=sectionId, NSValidationErrorValue=null}",
```

I get that error for sectionId, scId, and pointId only. All the other values come up fine. It applies to every object I try.

My code:

```
private func migrateData() {
    let context = persistenceController.container.viewContext
    
    let cdChazaraPoints = printCDChazaraPoints()
    for cdChazara in printCDChazaras() {
        if cdChazaraPoints.contains(where: { cp in
            cp.sectionId == cdChazara.sectionId && cp.scId == cdChazara.sectionId
        }) {
            print("CDChazaraPoint already exists for CDChazara (\(cdChazara.id ?? "nil"))")
        } else {
            guard let id = cdChazara.id, let sectionId = cdChazara.sectionId, let scId = cdChazara.scId else {
                print("Skipping CDChazaraPoint for CDChazara (\(cdChazara.id ?? "nil")")
                continue
            }
            print("Creating and saving CDChazaraPoint for CDChazara (\(cdChazara.id ?? "nil")")
            
            let state = CDChazaraState(context: context)
            state.stateId = IDGenerator.generate(withPrefix: "CS")
            state.date = cdChazara.date
            state.status = 4
            
            let cp = CDChazaraPoint(context: context)
            cp.chazaraState = state
            cp.pointId = id
            cp.sectionId = sectionId
            cp.scId = scId
            
            print("COPIED CDChazaraPoint: ID=\(cp.pointId ?? "nil") SECID=\(cp.sectionId ?? "nil") SCID=\(cp.scId ?? "nil") DATE=\(cp.chazaraState?.date?.description ?? "nil") STATUS=\(cp.chazaraState?.status ?? -3)")
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                print("Couldn't migrate data: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you!

[image: CDChazaraPoint]

[image: CDChazaraState]

Comment: You are setting sectionId for CDChazaraPoint but the error is for CDChazaraState

Comment: That is strange; the child object (CDChazaraState) doesn't have those values. Any idea why it is asking me for them? Those are values of the parent.

Comment: I added pictures of the data model. Maybe that can help.

Comment: The parent entity of the CDChazaraState is marked as CDChazaraPoint, but I don't know if that means it should be using inheritance. It should be an object that owns a smaller object.

Comment: I removed my comment since I see that it is not inheritance but it is strange that the log message mixes attributes from both entities like it does.

Comment: Not sure what is going on, I would as a first step use the debugger or print statements to verify that the object identifiers are the same as the one in the error message. `print(state.objectID)` and the same for `cp`, do this before the `save()` call

Comment: The parent of one of the objects should have been set to "no parent." Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent of one of the objects should have been set to "no parent." Therefore, it was inheriting and expecting parent values to be set.